# HTML5 Changing src on video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm trying to change the source of a video-element on my page, but i can't get it to work properly. I think this should work, but for some reason it doesn't.
I read up on similar questions and looked up the Apple Developer Library.

Here's how I'm trying to change the source:

```
<head>
<script>
    function play_red()
    { 
       var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
       vid.src = "videos\color_red.mp4"
       vid.load();
       vid.play();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="vid" src="videos\color_black.mp4" autoplay="true"></video>

<button type="button" onclick="play_red()"></button>
```

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:
Solution: don't translate your filenames when you ask stuff. i should've used

```
vid.setAttrivute('src','videos/color_rot.mp4);
```

instead.
I feel stupid now, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sudhir not that i can tell, i'm a newbie with HTML and JS

Comment: Why is there a forward slash in the function, but a backslash in the video tag?   Could that cause any issues?

Comment: @Dan i tried it with both backslashes and forward slashes, but it doesn't make any difference. And i made a typo in the question, editing it

Comment: Please go ahead and mark one of the answers as the true answer :)

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code into my own html file exactly, but just changed the video URLs to two of my own and it worked perfectly at least in Safari and Chrome for the Mac.  Are you sure the second video is encoded properly?

Comment: @Dan Yeah, it works perfectly fine now. i shouldn't mix german filenames with english ones, it'll only confuse me in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
function play_red()
{ 
   var vid = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
   vid.setAttribute('src', 'videos/color_red.mp4');
   vid.load();
   vid.play();
}
```

This should actually change the source. I'm not sure about the load() and play() functions though.

Comment: Sadly not, same result. After i press the button, the previous video vanishes, i can still see the controls and nothing happens. When i try on a iPad with Safari, the video seems to be infinitely loading. But the path is correct.

Comment: Did you check in the console whether the attribute changes or not? I'm not too familiar with HTML5 videos, so I don't know about the load() and play() videos. The attribute should be changed though...

Comment: Now this works, it probably worked before but i put in the wrong path. i feel pretty silly now

Comment: Don't feel silly. Even the best programmers find themselves doing these kind of mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `document.getElementById`:

```
<script>

function play_red()
{ 
   var vid = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].src = "videos/color_red.mp4";
   vid.load();
   vid.play();
}
</script>
```

If your willing to use jquery it's simple:

```
$("#vid").attr("src","videos/color_red.mp4");
```

Comment: check my updated code.It's probably not working bcoz you have more then one video tag in you webpage.

Answer (score 0):

U need to change:

```
<script> 
function play_red() 
{ 
var vid = document.getElementById("a");
vid.innerHTML  = ' <video id="vid" src="videos\color_red.mp4" autoplay="true"></video>';

 } 
 </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
 <div id="a">
 <video id="vid" src="videos\color_black.mp4" autoplay="true"></video>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="play_red()"></button>
```